# Is there an invisible padding/margin for font-size?

Tags: html, css, font-size

I am having a hard time understanding how font-size is working in the following html snippet:

```
.container {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: blue;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: white;
}

ul li span {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#test1 li {
    font-size: 48px;
}

#test2 li {
    font-size: 42px;
}​

<div class="container">
    <ul id="test1">
        <li><span>Test</span></li>        
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <ul id="test2">
        <li><span>Test</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

I want my `li` element to be exactly 50 pixels tall, and I want the text/span to be centered vertically within it. Everything is vertical, but when I set font-size to 48px with a 2px red border, the border is pushed outside of the li element. It almost seems like there is an invisible padding/margin applied.

Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating the "issue": http://jsfiddle.net/qtVK3/

When I inspect the `span` element in Chrome, it shows the actual height of the span element is 57px. Where does the extra 7px come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
display: inline-block
```

Is needed in the span because it is an inline elements. By default you cannot add top or bottom padding to an inline element only left and right. So the span will be padded even if you put padding to 0.

Also you need to change your line-height to 48px.

> line-height: 48px;

Comment: Do I need both height and line-height?

Comment: @Dismissile : no, as the line-height doesn't include the border so if it is set to 50px it will sum to 52px including the 1px surrounding border.
The height includes everything altogether

Answer (score 0):

you're missing the line-height (the space that separates multiple lines of text) - this is added to the height of the font.

Instead of setting the font size explicitly in pixels (bad form for accessibility), you should be setting the height of the containing element to the desired size

edit: I'm being thick.  margins / borders are added outside the content box.  You've set the line-height to 50px, so the border will be in addition to the 50px, hence appearing outside the element.

My comment about setting fonts in pixels still stands though.

Comment: No I'm not. I set line-height in the li element.

Comment: But the border is only 1px on top and bottom meaning the height is only 52px not 57px.